# Stuck in scanning bunch of space separated Strings using 'nextLine()'

Tags: java, string, java.util.scanner

I'm solving a programming challenge on hacker-earth, in which I've to scan a large number of space separated `String`s. To scan such a String I used `nextLine()` method,about which I've read [here.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13102045/skipping-nextline-after-using-next-nextint-or-other-nextfoo-methods) But It works only first time in the following `while()` loop. and after that nothing is scanned or printed in output.Here is my code:

```
Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
int t = in.nextInt();
while(t-->0){
        in.nextLine();
        String s = in.nextLine();
        String str[] = s.split(" ");

        for(int i=0;i<str.length/2;i++){
            String temp;
            temp = str[i];
            str[i] = str[str.length-i-1];
            str[str.length-i-1] = temp;
        }

        for(int i=0;i<str.length;i++){
            System.out.print(str[i]+" ");
        }    
   }
```

I've Input like this:

```
2                              //number of Strings to be Scanned.
Hello World
Hello StackOverFlow Users
```

For the first String `Hello World`, output comes perfectly fine,but nothing happens after this output. What I'm doing wrong here? Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Your loop is ending, because the counter `t` goes to zero after the second iteration.  This is why nothing is happening.  You can try increasing the value of `t` to a higher number, or you can allow the user to enter a special value to indicate that he wants the program to terminate.

Comment: why are you using `nextLine()` twice?

Comment: But I've already taken the value of `t` from user

Comment: @dabadaba see this :: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13102045/skipping-nextline-after-using-next-nextint-or-other-nextfoo-methods#

Comment: but don't use it twice in the `while` loop. Use it just right after `nextInt()`, outside of the loop. I think that's why the second line is being skipped.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen I've tried increasing `t` but nothing happened .

Comment: I don't think there's anything wrong with `t`, just try what I told you.

Comment: You are calling `nextLine()` twice.  Stop this, and call it once.

Answer (score 0):

As @dabadaba and @Tim Biegeleisen mentioned I removed first `in.nextLine()` from my code. but after that I've to increase `t` by `1` after user enters it. This worked for me!

Here is the correct code:

```
     Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
     int t = in.nextInt();
     t=t+1;
   while(t-->0){
          //  in.nextLine();
        String s = in.nextLine();

        String str[] = s.split(" ");

        for(int i=0;i<str.length/2;i++){
            String temp;
            temp = str[i];
            str[i] = str[str.length-i-1];
            str[str.length-i-1] = temp;
        }

        for(int i=0;i<str.length;i++){
            System.out.print(str[i]+" ");
    }

   }
```

Thanks for help.

Comment: You don't need to increase `t`. Just change the `while` condition.